# Is "at the edge of" natural in the context?

Tags: idioms

> The cemetery is located **at the edge of** the city.

Is "at the edge of" natural in this context? Or are there other options that would be more natural?

Comment: The expression is fine. Alternatives (not improvements) might be **on the fringes, at the limits**,

Comment: @RonaldSole Is "at the edge" a correct phrase/idiom? I can't find any meanings of it anywhere.